# How to calculate difference between two datetime in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I am using telerik controls and i want difference between two datetime variables how can i calculate.

```
var x=9/1/2012 10:20:00 AM;
var y=9/1/2012 09:00:00 AM;
```

I want difference between two times throw javascript in to another variable as number.

Comment: C# or JavaScript? Please choose *one* .. also, please use *valid code*. (That is invalid syntax in both C# *and* JavaScript.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) type variable and then calculate the difference using `-` operator, you will get difference in milliseconds.

```
var first = new Date(2012,8,1,10,20,0,0); 
var second = new Date(2012, 9, 1, 09, 00, 0, 0); 
var difference = (second - first); // difference in milliseconds
```

Here is [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVzGA/)

Answer (score 2):

You should try something on these lines

```
var a = new Date('9/1/2012 10:20:00 AM');
var b = new Date('9/1/2012 09:00:00 AM');
// a - b  this should give you the diff
var diff = a - b;
alert(diff/1000); // this should be value in seconds i.e 4800
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript)

Basically, put those two dates into Date objects, and subtract one from the other.  That will give you the difference in milliseconds and you can work from there to get larger time segments.