# Is adding months with the JavaScript `Date` object standards based?

Tags: javascript, date, standards

The following JavaScript produces the results as indicated:

```
  dat0 = new Date(2012, 9, 31);
  dat0.setMonth(dat0.getMonth() + 1); // Oct 31 + 1 month = Dec. 1

  dat1 = new Date(2011, 0, 31); // Jan 31 (non leap year)
  dat1.setMonth(dat1.getMonth() + 1);  // Mar 3

  dat2 = new Date(2012, 0, 31); // Jan 31 (leap year)
  dat2.setMonth(dat2.getMonth() + 1); // Mar 2

  dat3 = new Date(2011, 11, 31); // Dec 31
  dat3.setMonth(dat3.getMonth() - 1); // minus one month is Dec 1

  dat4 = new Date(2011, 10, 30); // Nov 30
  dat4.setMonth(dat4.getMonth() - 1); // minus one month is Oct 30

  alert(dat0 + "\n" + dat1 + "\n" + dat2 + "\n" + dat3 + "\n" + dat4);
```

I've tested this in IE 9 and Chrome and the results are the same. Can I therefore assume that all JavaScript implementations will produce the same results? In other words, are these results dictated by an agreed to standard?

(I'm not surprised that adding one month to Oct. 31 results in Dec 1. But what I find very surprising is adding one month to Jan 31 results in two different dates in March with neither date being March 1st.)

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf5da/).

**Related Note:** For those interested, I'm writing a `closure` designed to handle additional date math functionality beyond what the `Date` object provides. (Add/subtract months, months between two dates, is last day of month, is leap year, etc.) I know I could extend the `Date` object (via prototypes) but there are reasons for not doing that. In any event, there is an `addMonths` function that, when adding one month to Jan. 31, returns a result that is always the last day of Feb. Adding one month to Oct. 31 returns Nov 30.

You may try the code using this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQkpn/).

Comments, questions or suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Related: http://es5.github.com/x15.9.html#x15.9

Comment: @icktoofay Good information. Thanks. At first I had assumed that a month was defined as `X` number of milliseconds. That would explain why adding one month to Jan 31 produces different results in March depending on whether or not it is a leap year. But then, subtracting one month from either March date should result in Jan. 31. It does not. So there does not seem to be a definition of a _month_ which is how it should be considering months are not of equal duration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between dates in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript)