# Date difference not more than 90 days

Tags: javascript

I need to compare two dates (entered through textbox using calendar extender dd/MM/yyyy format) difference not exceed more than 3 months(90 days..)How will i do it in javascript?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript

Comment: please refer thin link .It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Did you put any efforts on this

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you have to do is to create a `Date` object from the input string. If it is like `21/11/2013`, you have to do call `split('/')` on this string to get the day, month and year.

You can do this with the two dates and compare them.

Comment: sorry, i thought i was escaping '\'

Answer (score 0):

```
function dateDiff(d1str, d2str) {
    var d1 = new Date(d1str),
        d2 = new Date(d2str);
    return (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 // diff in days
}


dateDiff("11/11/2011", "11/12/2011"); // returns: 1
```