# Difference between two times in format (hh: mm: ss)

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I have two times, let say:

```
t1= '05:34:01' ;
t2= '20:44:44' ;
```

I want two evaluate difference between these two times in same format. Like the result of above must come as

```
t3= t2 - t1;  // 15:10:43
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Highly recommend you include [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in your project if you need to handle time.

Example:

```
var t1 = moment('05:34:01', "hh:mm:ss");
var t2 = moment('20:44:44', "hh:mm:ss");
var t3 = moment(t2.diff(t1)).format("hh:mm:ss");
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/H6y26/)

To install moment.js in [Node.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/), simply do:

`npm install moment` (or for a global install `sudo npm -g install moment`)

And then in your Node.js, include it like so:

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

*Edit*: For 24h clock, change `hh` to `HH`.

Comment: oh..now I noticed, the difference that I am getting is in 12 hr format. I actually needs 24 hr format like I mentioned in my question. I want answer to be like 15:10:43, but it is returning 03:10:43. Can you suggest how to get desired output.

Comment: simply use `HH` instead of `hh`

Comment: @brandonscript, I am getting `12:10:43` value when I am running the fiddle (JFYI, I am in Tokyo). Is it something related to UTC? If yes how we can resolve it? Please suggest.

Comment: Probably. Try setting the timezone for both moment objects? Not sure why they wouldn’t default to the same TZ though.

Answer (score 5):

I would also go with the `moment.js` but you could do:

```
function time_diff(t1, t2) {
   var parts = t1.split(':');
   var d1 = new Date(0, 0, 0, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
   parts = t2.split(':');
   var d2 = new Date(new Date(0, 0, 0, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]) - d1);
   // this would also work
   // d2.toTimeString().substr(0, d2.toTimeString().indexOf(' '));
   return (d2.getHours() + ':' + d2.getMinutes() + ':' + d2.getSeconds());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also used `momentjs` but with `duration` and got correct different between times:

```
var t1 = moment('05:34:01', "HH:mm:ss");
var t2 = moment('20:44:44', "HH:mm:ss");

var start_date = moment(t1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var end_date = moment(t2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var duration = moment.duration(end_date.diff(t1));

var t3 = duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
alert(t3);
console.log(duration.hours());
console.log(duration.minutes());
console.log(duration.seconds());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function time_diff(t1, t2) 
{
  var t1parts = t1.split(':');    
  var t1cm=Number(t1parts[0])*60+Number(t1parts[1]);

  var t2parts = t2.split(':');    
  var t2cm=Number(t2parts[0])*60+Number(t2parts[1]);

  var hour =Math.floor((t1cm-t2cm)/60);    
  var min=Math.floor((t1cm-t2cm)%60);    
  return (hour+':'+min+':00'); 
}

time_diff("02:23:00","00:45:00")
```