# Check if date object is over one year old

Tags: javascript

I would like to see if a date object is over one year old! I don't know how to even compare them due to the leap years etc..

```
var oldDate = new Date("July 21, 2001 01:15:23");
var todayDate = new Date();

if(???) {
    console.log("it has been over one year!");
} else {
    console.log("it has not gone one year yet!");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between dates in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Note [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2400624/1324) which specifically shows how to alert when the difference is > 365 days.

Answer (score 5):

You could make the check like this

```
(todayDate - oldDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365) > 1
```

You can see and try it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rnyxzLc2/

Answer (score 1):

This code should handle leap years correctly.

Essentially:

If the difference between the dates' `getFullYear()` is more than one,
or the difference equals one *and* `todayDate` is greater than `oldDate` after setting their years to be the same,
then there's more than a one-year difference.

```js
var oldDate = new Date("Oct 2, 2014 01:15:23"),
    todayDate = new Date(),
    y1= oldDate.getFullYear(),
    y2= todayDate.getFullYear(),
    d1= new Date(oldDate).setFullYear(2000),
    d2= new Date(todayDate).setFullYear(2000);

console.log(y2 - y1 > 1 || (y2 - y1 == 1 && d2 > d1));
```

Comment: setYear is deprecated, but it looks like setFullYear will work for this case

Answer (score -1):

use `getFullYear()`:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/husgce6w/

```
var oldDate = new Date("July 21, 2001 01:15:23");
var todayDate = new Date();
var thisYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
var thatYear = oldDate.getFullYear();
console.log(todayDate);
console.log(thatYear);

if(thisYear - thatYear > 1) {
    console.log("it has been over one year!");
} else {
    console.log("it has not gone one year yet!");
}
```

Comment: This would return true for dates that are only one day apart, in the case of 12/31/2015 vs 1/1/2016