# Getting Time Left (Countdown) -- Html, Javascript, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Basically, I'm trying to build a spaceship launch app that pulls data from say, a spreadsheet, and displays the time left for each spacecraft's launch. BTW, I did look at the (few) questions on Stack right now about getting time left, but they don't seem very comprehensive and I'm confused on how to implement them into my code.

Here's a snippet from my html:

```
<h2>Rocket Launch: {{launch.name}}</h2>
            <p>Time left: x minutes</p>
            <script>
            var currentdate = new Date(); 
            var datetime = (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
            </script>
```

As you can see, I'm using angularJS's $scope to get the launch's name in line 1. Then I'm trying to display the time left until the launch...but I'm kind of unsure how to do so? In the script part starting in line 3, I found out how to display the Current time/date, but how am I supposed to be able to display the time remaining (launchtime - currenttime) in the HTML? I'm kind of confused and would like a few pointers to guide me.

By the way, I'm just starting out in AngularJS and hoping to put something somewhat simple yet meaningful together. Sorry about pretty much being a newb.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the launch date located relatively to this code?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you meant by that, do you mind rephrasing that?

Comment: I mean can you access the date from launch.date? for example

Comment: Yeah, I can pull {{launch.date}} from my code to get the launch date--I'm just wondering how to do the subtraction currenttime-launchdate/time then display it in place of the Time left: *x* minutes

Comment: You can calculate the difference in JavaScript Date objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7763335/1828744

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took a few minutes to write up a countdown algorithm

```
$scope.CountDown = {
    getTimeRemaining: function(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    },

    initializeClock: function(endtime) {
      function updateClock() {
        var t = $scope.CountDown.getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        $scope.CountDown.days = t.days;
        $scope.CountDown.hours = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        $scope.CountDown.minutes = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        $scope.CountDown.seconds = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          $interval.cancel(timeinterval);
        }
      }

      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = $interval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is add the CountDown object to your scope and call `$scope.CountDown.initializeClock($scope.launch.date);`

I made a plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/x0BkVPgPLjD8rtbfADtY?p=preview

You can display CountDown.days, CountDown.hours, CountDown.minutes and CountDown.seconds on your html view

Comment: I'm happy I could be of assistance. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much! :)) Sorry about the delayed response...the code didn't work for a while and I had to play around with it but it finally did. You saved me ahhaahhaha!

Comment: Where we can pass the date to compare? I am not sure on which scope or variable i need to pass the date from database. At the moment it is auto generating the date. It starts from 24 hours.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine if you are not comparing to current datetime change "new Date()" to your custom compare date on line => var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());

Comment: @CalculatingMachine You could also export it to a parameter so you'll have the structure getTimeRemaining(starttime, endtime) and initializeClock(starttime, endtime)

Comment: @EfeOmoregieElijah can you make or update it on fiddle/plunker. It is quite hard for me to understand. Thanks for your comment. Voted up.

Comment: @EfeOmoregieElijah what would be the accepted date format?i tried dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy  also mm-dd-yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine You can use Date Object constructor new Date('<date_in_iso_format>'); where iso format is YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS https://plnkr.co/edit/hRrXG6Ah8E3Wl3nDN3vG

Answer (score 2):

This might help. Below is a pretty simple way to handle a basic countdown. Set the "counter" to any number. Then simply have a span with ID count in your html and it should do the trick. May be able to implement this into your code.

HTML:

```
 <span id="count"></span>
```

JS

```
var counter = 91;

setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering how I will be able to get the difference between the current time/date and the date/time of the launch?

Comment: Sure thing! I would say set the counter to the launch time/date and the (counter >= 0). to the current time/date.

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript). It discusses the how to find the difference between 2 dates. You would need to have you launch time in the date format along with the current time.

Now that you have both dates, here is where you need to get clever.

Part 1: The difference between the two dates will give you the difference in milliseconds, so you'll need to convert it back to the format you want (ie 0 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, 10 seconds etc).

Part 2: I'm assuming you'll want to update it every second so that it looks like a countdown. To do this, you will need to do everything I've described in a function and assign the result to a scope variable:

```
var countdown = function () {
    var launchTime = new Date(//whatever it is);
    var currentTime = new Date(//current Time);
    var difference = (launchTime - currentTime)
    $scope.currentTimeLeft = difference; //this is in milliseconds. If you don't want that you'll have to do some logic
}
```

Then in your html you'll be able to access the currentTimeLeft by this:

```
<p>Time left: {{currentTimeLeft}} minutes</p>
```

However, this will only calculate once and will be "old" literally after one second. So, you can add the setInterval function to call the countdown function every second.

```
setInterval(function(){ countdown() }, 1000); //1000 == 1 second.
```

You could also look at using the native AngularJS [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to call the countdown function every second.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped.