# Time difference between two date time string

Tags: javascript

I have two date time string.

```
var currentTime = '2/2/2018, 11:34:53 AM';
var loggedTime = '2/2/2018, 11:14:46 AM';
```

Can someone suggest how to get the time difference between two date times ?
If time difference is hour, days, months, the time difference should come as the same.

Comment: may be Duplicate,For a useful function to get the difference separated into seconds, minutes, hours, see the answer at [Difference between dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript/1968175#1968175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```js
var currentTime = '2/2/2018, 11:34:53 AM';
var loggedTime = '2/2/2018, 11:14:46 AM';
var current = new Date(currentTime);
var logged = new Date(loggedTime);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(current.getTime() - logged.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var remainingTime = timeDiff - (diffDays*1000*3600*24);
var hours = Math.floor(remainingTime/(1000*3600));
remainingTime = remainingTime - (hours*1000*3600);
var minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime/(1000*60));
remainingTime = remainingTime - (minutes*1000*60);
var seconds = Math.floor(remainingTime/(1000));
remainingTime = remainingTime - (seconds*1000);
var milliSeconds = remainingTime;
console.log(diffDays+' Days '+hours+ ' Hours '+minutes+' Minutes '+seconds+ ' Seconds '+milliSeconds+' MilliSeconds ');
```