# print the number of days from the selected date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to print the number of days from the selected date. Instead of printing the number of days  from the current date to the previous date,  it prints results it in milliseconds. snippet below

```
 $scope.countDays= function( d2) {
              var diff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - d2.getTime());
              alert(diff); //prints milliseconds
              return diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            };

<input ng-model="dateSelection" ng-change="countDays(dateSelection)">
```

how can I print the exact days difference in actual integer and disable future date selection

Comment: it's still a duplicate of that question, though. The answer is already there for you to fix what you've written.

Comment: @ADyson I have re-editted and reworded my problem/challenge

Comment: Ok but it's still a duplicate of about a dozen other questions...you just need to do some simple googling. Here's a good answer about getting the difference between different dates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968175/5947043

Comment: the SO link solutions is similar to what I did and getting milliseconds

Comment: okay.... looking deeper I used Math.round(...) and solved my problem. Thanks for giving it to me the hard way

Comment: please upvote me... thanks. It was a honest attempt from the mindset of a learner

Comment: you weren't getting milliseconds at all, you were just getting a number of days with some decimal points. As you say, rounding it will produce a neater end result, but it's still basically the same as all those other questions and answers. How to round a number is kind of a separate issue.

Comment: okay, thanks for the learning curve

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$scope.resumption = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30));
```

Comment: if you want to deal date , plesae use moment.js, [enter link description here][1], 

    moment.substract(30, 'days').calender()  // 30 days before now

  [1]: http://momentjs.cn/